# Audio editing program that acts like Premiere Pro

Tags: sound-editing, premiere, program

For simple audio editing, right now I use Premiere Pro. I know it's weird; using a video editor for audio editing, but it's the easiest for me right now...

So what I mainly like about cutting in Premiere, is that you can easily drag out the clip to regain what you may have already cut out. It's in a really easy-to-see layout of everything, you have all your assets on the left where you can drag them in to your timeline when you want them, and save them in the project panel when not yet to that audio clip. I also really like the simplicity of keyframes for effects and such.

I am making simple music mixes right now, so I need a way to easily cut the clips, drag out the ones I want back, easily apply effects, and so on. I just need more control, as PP wasn't built for editing audio. Are there any (free?) programs out there that specialize in audio editing but act like Adobe Premiere Pro?

Comment: FL Studio does the "drag and restore cut data" dealio (you can switch it between cutting and stretching when you do that), you have access to a library/project panel/sample bank for quickly adding and removing audio, it has one of the quickest and easiest ways of applying and previewing effects on channels and audio files etc.  The demo would be worth your time checking out, as long as you don't get overwhelmed by all the features packed into it.

Comment: If you refer to the possibility to "resize" audio objects (i.e. trim the start and end) most DAWs I have worked with support this.

Answer (score 1):

Most DAWs should be able to accomplish this. That said I think you should check out Reaper. You can keyframe, as well as draw envelopes/curves. It also has ripple delete which is nice, and some video editing features as well. Premiere is clunky when working with audio, I think you'll find Reaper much more fluid. The only thing I'm not sure about is saving the audio files as temporary assets to re-use, but it might have that as well.
Not free but the trial lasts forever and if it fits the need, you pay and the fee is minimal particularly compared to other DAWs. 
www.reaper.fm